# Passing an Array pointer and printing

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, parameters

Despite my efforts to resolve my problem, whenever I compile my code it either has errors or fails immediately. My goal is to create an array of characters in my `'run_program'` function, and then pass that array (as a pointer so I can instantly return the changes) to my `my_str_n_cat` function. Unfortunately  suck at coding so I can't get it to print. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//Task #1 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
char my_str_n_cat (char *source_ptr)
{
    (*source_ptr);
    printf("My Name Is %s", *source_ptr);

}

//Main ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
int run_program ()
{
    int ;
    char source[6] = {'D', 'I', 'L', 'L', 'O', 'N'}, destination[10];
    char *source_ptr, *destination_ptr;

    source_ptr = source;

    my_str_n_cat(&source_ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are more than one problem,

1. This definition,

   ```
   char source[6] = {'D', 'I', 'L', 'L', 'O', 'N'}
   ```

   cannot be printed with `printf()` like you tried.

   The `printf()` function, with the `"%s"` specifier expects a pointer to a string as a parameter, yours is not a string strictly speaking.

   For it to be a string, it needs a terminating `nul` byte, `'\0'`, so this would be correct

   ```
   char source[7] = {'D', 'I', 'L', 'L', 'O', 'N', '\0'}
   ```
2. You dereference the pointer when you pass it to `printf()`, you shouldn't, remove the `*` before `source_ptr`.
3. You are passing the address of the array, and you don't need to because the array name is equivalent to a pointer to the first element of the array, so this

   ```
   my_str_n_cat(source_ptr);
   ```

   would be sufficient.

   The main difference here is the type of the pointer, which gives the compiler information to be used when you do pointer arithmetic or when you dereference the pointer through the subscript operator, which is essentially the same.

   In this case nothing speciall will happen, because the poitner is being converted to the correct pointer type.

   This is one of the things that indicates that you did not enable compiler warnings.

The fact that you don't say that there were **warnings** from your compiler, means that you didn't enable them, you should always let your compiler help you find mistakes that are very common, that's why most compiler have good diagnosis features, and you can enable them by giving switches to the compiler command.

Comment: And while you're at it, the statement `(*source_ptr);` does nothing. It's equivalent to `69;`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately my `my_str_n_cat(&source_ptr)` has an error saying "no instance of overloaded function 'my_str_n_cat' matches the argument list argument types are: (char**)" Any idea of how to fix this? When I remove the ambersand, It just prints the string ass null.

Comment: @DillonJ. you are using a **c++** compiler and that is because of the third point in my answer, you are passing a pointer of incompatible type. If you are working with c, you need to configure your environment so it uses the right compiler.

Comment: @iharob I see I am in a college course, and this is what they gave me, I set it up just like my prof. Thanks for the feedback, I will look into how to change my environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need a better understanding of pointer [here](http://boredzo.org/pointers/) an easy one.

```
char my_str_n_cat (char *source_ptr)
{
   printf("My Name Is %s\n", source_ptr);

}

//Main ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
int run_program ()
{
  char source[6] = {'D', 'I', 'L', 'L', 'O', 'N'}, destination[10];
  char *source_ptr, *destination_ptr;

  source_ptr = source;

  my_str_n_cat(source_ptr);
}
```

Comment: You didn't explain anything at all initially.

Comment: @issathink I think something is wrong with my environment according to iharob, since this prints "My Name is <null>" thank you for your help